# Why are security_path_* symbols missing from kallsyms and System.map on kernel version 5.4.156?

Tags: linux, ebpf, kprobe

I am failing to load an eBPF script that traces path renames by using kprobe:

```cpp
int kprobe__security_path_rename( struct pt_regs *ctx, const struct path *old_dir, struct dentry *old_dentry, const struct path *new_dir, struct dentry *new_dentry )
{
    ...
}
```

It works fine on my Ubuntu machine (kernel 5.13.0), but fails on an AWS node (kernel 5.4.156) with the following error:

```sh
sh-4.2$ sudo ./tracker.py
cannot attach kprobe, probe entry may not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tracker.py", line 698, in <module>
    bpf = BPF(text=program)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 372, in __init__
    self._trace_autoload()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 1232, in _trace_autoload
    fn_name=fn.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 684, in attach_kprobe
    (fn_name, event))
Exception: Failed to attach BPF program b'kprobe__security_path_rename' to kprobe b'security_path_rename'
```

I checked `/proc/kallsyms` and `/boot/System.map-$(uname -r)` and indeed the symbols `security_path_{mknod,mkdir,unlink,rename}` all exist on my machine and are missing on the AWS node.

I also observed that after updating the AWS kernel version to 5.4.176 the symbols appear and my program works. However, these symbols all appear in the source of all (relevant) kernel versions, are **not** marked `static` or `notrace` and are explicitly exported via `EXPORT_SYMBOL`.

Can't these symbols be kprobed on kernel 5.4.156?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause. The problem was not directly related to kernel versions, but rather to kernel config.

Apparently, the kernel version 5.4.156 for AWS nodes was configured without `CONFIG_SECURITY_PATH`, while newer kernel 5.4.176 for the same node was configured with this flag. In the former configuration, the `security_path_*` symbols mention in the question do not exist since their whole code path is guarded with `#ifdef`s.

One can test which kernel configuration flags are enabled by inspecting the config file, e.g. use one of the following commands:

```sh
grep CONFIG_SECURITY_PATH /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

```sh
grep CONFIG_SECURITY_PATH /boot/config
```

```sh
gunzip < /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_SECURITY_PATH
```